# Ant: If property contains certain string, change the name of the property

Tags: ant

I am trying to check a folder's name, and if it contains a certain string, I want that folder path to be changed.

So far I came up with this:

```
<property name="component.release.dir" value="${install.dir}/${component.name}" />
            <!-- Check if the component is a part of projectL -->
            <condition property="projectLFolderSpotted">
                <matches pattern="projectL" string="${component.release.dir}"/>
                <!-- if so, put the component in an appropriate folder -->
                <property name="component.release.dir" value="${install.dir}/projectL/${component.name}" />
                <echo message="projectL component has been detected, and moved accordingly!"/>
            </condition>
```

But I get the following error:

```
condition doesn't support the nested "property" element.
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties in ANT are immutable, once they're assigned a value it doesn't change.

Here's how I'd suggest you do it:

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <property name="release.dir.seed" location="build/helloworld"/>

  <condition property="release.dir" value="build/found/helloworld" else="build/notfound/helloworld">
    <contains string="${release.dir.seed}" substring="helloworld"/>
  </condition>

  <target name="build">
    <echo message="Result: ${release.dir}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```